# What is the Windows keyboard shortcut for changing case in selected text?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

for when we use <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename filenames and after that I want to change the case of those filenames

Comment: There isn't a keyboard shortcut built in, I'm fairly sure. You might be able to make this happen, but I really can't imagine how. I played with autohotkey a little and don't see a worthwhile way. Nice idea though, good luck.

Comment: Do you only want to do this when renaming a file, or also in other contexts? If it's just for file renaming, you could say that in the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a quick AutoHotkey script I threw together which is tailored to your specific situation (tested and working):

```
!r::
save := ClipboardAll
Send ^c
clipwait
oldclip := Clipboard
StringLower, newclip, oldclip
If (newclip == oldclip)
{
    StringUpper, newclip, oldclip
}
Clipboard := newclip
Send ^v{Enter}
Clipboard := save
return
```

After pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename, using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> will change the folder's case. If you want to **swap case** of each letter separately, well, that's something different entirely. I know most people on here aren't very appreciative of animated GIFs embedded directly on the page, so if you'd like to see it in action, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh31E.gif).

Comment: thx and can we also add dashes in place of spaces between text

Comment: see my this question - http://superuser.com/questions/86392/how-to-replace-spaces-with-dashes

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script for this as suggested by outsideblasts in the comments.

Check out [**toggle/cycle through capitalize-lowercase-uppercase**](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic20025.html) in the AutoHotkey forums. The final version of the script is at the bottom of the page. Select all the code, put it in a .ahk script and run it (it implies you have AutoHotkey installed of course).

I tested it and it works fine in the Explorer and most editors. When the filename is selected, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to toggle the case of the text.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this in AHK

```
#SingleInstance Force

k := 1
<Shift::
save := ClipboardAll
Clipboard =
Send ^c
oldclip := Clipboard

if(newclip == oldclip){
}
else{
k := 1
}

if(StrLen(oldclip) = 0){
   msgbox, jai ganesh!
   return
}
else if (k = 1){ ;to inverse case 

newclip:= ""
 Loop % Strlen(oldclip) {
    Lab_Invert_Char:= Substr(oldclip, A_Index, 1)
    if Lab_Invert_Char is upper
       newclip:= newclip Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) + 32)
    else if Lab_Invert_Char is lower
       newclip:= newclip Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) - 32)
    else
       newclip:= newclip Lab_Invert_Char
}
else if(k = 2){ ;to lower case 
StringLower, newclip, oldclip

}
else if(k = 3){ ;to upper case 
StringUpper, newclip, oldclip
}
else if(k = 4){ ;to sentence case
 StringUpper newclip, oldclip, T
 }
}
k++
if (k = 5){
    k := 1
}
Clipboard := newclip
Send ^v
x:=StrLen(Clipboard)
Send {shift down}{Left %x%}{shift up}
Clipboard := save
return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#SingleInstance Force
k := 1
<Shift::
save := ClipboardAll
Clipboard =
Send ^c
oldclip := Clipboard
if(newclip == oldclip){
}
else{
    k := 1
        if(StrLen(oldclip) = 0){
           msgbox, jai ganesh!
           return
        }
    }

     if (k = 1){ ;to inverse case 
        newclip:= ""
         Loop % Strlen(oldclip) {
            Lab_Invert_Char:= Substr(oldclip, A_Index, 1)
            if Lab_Invert_Char is upper
               newclip:= newclip Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) + 32)
            else if Lab_Invert_Char is lower
               newclip:= newclip Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) - 32)
            else
               newclip:= newclip Lab_Invert_Char
            }  
        }       
    else if(k = 2){ ;to lower case 
        StringLower, newclip, oldclip
    }
    else if(k = 3){ ;to upper case 
        Stringupper, Newclip, Oldclip
    }
    else if(k = 4){ ;to sentence case
     StringUpper newclip, oldclip, T
     }
k++
if (k = 5){
    k := 1
}
Clipboard := newclip
Send ^v
x:=StrLen(Clipboard)
Send {shift down}{Left %x%}{shift up}
Clipboard := save
return
```