# How to replace spaces with dashes?

Tags: windows, find-and-replace

I am looking to replace spaces between words in a field with dashes "-"

Example:

From: "See it here"
To: "See-it-here"

1. customer faqs
2. how we can help
3. planning your budget
4. customer case
5. studies tenant

Should be easy is the any online or offline tool

Thanks for any help.

Comment: see edited question

Comment: You may want to let people know this is based on your other question ( http://superuser.com/questions/86376 ) or else you're going to get a lot of solutions involving text editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is based on your [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/86376), the easiest method would be to highlight the specified string, then use another [hotkey](http://autohotkey.com) (tested and working):

```
!-::
save := ClipboardAll
Send ^c
clipwait
oldclip := Clipboard
StringReplace, clipboard, oldclip, %A_SPACE%, -, All
Send ^v{Enter}
Clipboard := save
oldclip = 
return
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> can then replace all spaces with dashes in the currently selected text (if the control is editable).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) to search and replace a regular expression in your text. You should look for all spaces *within* words only.

[image: Replace a regular expression]

Comment: how with which regex command