# How can I combine two AutoHotkey scripts into one?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

I want to combine the following two scripts into one:

- [How to replace spaces with dashes?](https://superuser.com/questions/86392/how-to-replace-spaces-with-dashes)
- [What is the windows keyboard shortcut for changing case in selected text?](https://superuser.com/questions/86376)

How can I do this?

Note that whenever I use these AutoHotkey scripts with form input, it presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key automatically which I don't want.

Comment: Those 2 links are identical. Do you mean http://superuser.com/questions/86376 ?

Comment: oh yes i changed correct link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select text, press Alt-R

Converts:
"My Filename" to "my-filename"
"MY FILENAME" to "my-filename"
"my filename" to "MY-FILENAME"
Preserves original clipboard contents

```
#SingleInstance Force

!r::
save := ClipboardAll
Send ^c
clipwait
original_filename := Clipboard
StringReplace, hyphen_filename, original_filename, %A_SPACE%, -, All
StringLower, hyphen_filename_toggle, hyphen_filename
If (hyphen_filename_toggle == hyphen_filename)
{
    StringUpper, hyphen_filename_toggle, hyphen_filename
}
Clipboard := hyphen_filename_toggle
Send ^v
Clipboard := save
return
```

Comment: Tested and working. Based on the two linked scripts of John T.

Comment: Sorry i was out from city to celebrate party. yes it's working thanks