# How to make a seperate standalone exe for any single or multiple Autohotkey script which i like and want to send a non-geek friend

Tags: windows, autohotkey

i want to make for this script

[How can I combine two AutoHotkey scripts into one?](https://superuser.com/questions/90125/how-to-combine-2-autohotkey-script-into-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) comes with a tool called ahk2exe. It will compile the scripts into an executable.

[image]

Comment: where is this tool in Autohotkey

Comment: In this zip file, inside the **compiler** folder: http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoHotkey.zip

Answer (score 1):

During installation the installer will ask you if you would like the ability to convert your `*.AHK` scripts to standalone executables. If you click the box next to install *Stand Alone AHK Compiler*, you will have this option available.

If you rush through installation and do not notice that this is not selected by default, you will not install this option, and will not have the associated `ahk2.exe` program installed.